Disabling ipv6 on Windows 10 breaks connectivity
I have problems with Windows not using ipv4 when ipv6 is not available. For example stackoverflow doesn't serve ipv6 and when I try to open it, Firefox says it can't find the server.
However, disabling ipv6 in the properties of my Ethernet connection breaks the connectivity entirely.
What can I do to solve this problem?

Do you actually have IPv4 connectivity at all?

@security_paranoid I don't know if that makes any sense

@grawity I skimmed over and misread the question, and then wrote my comment in a rush. You’re right… it makes no sense at all. I thought the OP was talking about their LAN.

You should set Windows to "Prefer IPv4 over IPv6", by modifying the registey.
You can follow these steps to modify the registry key:

Note: HKLM can be substituted for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.


Open an administrative Command Prompt window.
Run the following command:
reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters" /v DisabledComponents

Normally, registry key value DisabledComponents does not yet exist. So the expected out should be as shown below.
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

Or, if the value does exist, then the output should be as follows.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters
    DisabledComponents    REG_DWORD    0x0

If the output is as shown below, then you already have "Prefer IPv4 over IPv6". In this case, you do not need to complete the rest of the steps.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters
    DisabledComponents    REG_DWORD    0x20

If none of the above is output, then you should not proceed with the rest of the steps. You need to see the website "Guidance for configuring IPv6 in Windows for advanced users" for further instructions.
Run the following command:
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters" /v DisabledComponents /t REG_DWORD /d 0x20 /f


Restart the computer.

Explanation:
The following was take from "Guidance for configuring IPv6 in Windows for advanced users".

Use registry key to configure IPv6

Important
 
Follow the steps in this section carefully. Serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Before you modify it, back up the registry for restoration in case problems occur.

The IPv6 functionality can be configured by modifying the following registry key:
Location: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters\
Name: DisabledComponents`
Type: REG_DWORD
Min Value: 0x00 (default value)
Max Value: 0xFF (IPv6 disabled)



IPv6 Functionality
Registry value and comments




Prefer IPv4 over IPv6
Decimal 32Hexadecimal 0x20Binary xx1x xxxxRecommended instead of disabling IPv6.To confirm preference of IPv4 over IPv6, perform the following commands:- Open the command prompt or PowerShell.- Use the 'ping' command to check the preferred IP version. For example, "ping bing.com".- If IPv4 is preferred, you should see an IPv4 address being returned in the response.Network Connections:- Open the command prompt or PowerShell.- Use 'netsh interface ipv6 show prefixpolicies- Check if the 'Prefix' policies have been modified to prioritize IPv4.- The '::ffff:0:0/96' prefix should have a higher precedence than the '::/0' prefix.For Example, if you have two entries, one with precedence 35 and another with precedence 40, the one with precedence 40 will be preferred.


Disable IPv6
Decimal 255Hexadecimal 0xFFBinary 1111 1111See startup delay occurs after you disable IPv6 in Windows if you encounter startup delay after disabling IPv6 in Windows 7 SP1 or Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1.Additionally, system startup will be delayed for five seconds if IPv6 is disabled by incorrectly, setting the DisabledComponents registry setting to a value of 0xffffffff. The correct value should be 0xff. For more information, see Internet Protocol Version 6 (IPv6) Overview.The DisabledComponents registry value doesn't affect the state of the check box. Even if the DisabledComponents registry key is set to disable IPv6, the check box in the Networking tab for each interface can be checked. This is an expected behavior.You cannot completely disable IPv6 as IPv6 is used internally on the system for many TCPIP tasks. For example, you will still be able to run ping ::1 after configuring this setting.


Disable IPv6 on all nontunnel interfaces
Decimal 16Hexadecimal 0x10Binary xxx1 xxxx


Disable IPv6 on all tunnel interfaces
Decimal 1Hexadecimal 0x01Binary xxxx xxx1


Disable IPv6 on all nontunnel interfaces (except the loopback) and on IPv6 tunnel interface
Decimal 17Hexadecimal 0x11Binary xxx1 xxx1


Prefer IPv6 over IPv4
Binary xx0x xxxx


Re-enable IPv6 on all nontunnel interfaces
Binary xxx0 xxxx


Re-enable IPv6 on all tunnel interfaces
Binary xxxx xxx0


Re-enable IPv6 on nontunnel interfaces and on IPv6 tunnel interfaces
Binary xxx0 xxx0





The problem solved itself out of nowhere. I'll keep this in case it happens again and will mark this as the answer.
